# Python 2.7: detect emoji from text

Tags: unicode, emoji

I'd like to be able to detect emoji in text and look up their names.

I've had no luck using unicodedata module and I suspect that I'm not
understanding the UTF-8 conventions.

I'd guess that I need to load my doc as as utf-8, then break the unicode "strings" into unicode symbols. Iterate over these and look them up.

```
#new example loaded using pandas and encoding UTF-8                     
'A man tried to get into my car\U0001f648'          

type(test) = unicode

import unicodedata as uni
uni.name(test[0])
Out[89]: 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A'

uni.name(test[-3])
Out[90]: 'LATIN SMALL LETTER R'    

uni.name(test[-1])
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-417c561246c2> in <module>()
----> 1 uni.name(test[-1])
ValueError: no such name

# just to be clear
uni.name(u'\U0001f648')
ValueError: no such name
```

I looked up the unicode symbol via google and it's a legit symbol.
Perhaps the unicodedata module isn't very comprehensive...?

I'm considering making my own look up table from [here](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt).
Interested in other ideas...this one seems do-able.

Comment: That string doesn't contain what you think it does. Try printing it.

Comment: Yeah I didn't look for emojii here I just grabbed something...but I will

Comment: What I mean is, it's not a Unicode string. It's a byte string that looks like it contains some [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). `unicodedata` isn't going to work if you feed it garbage.

Comment: mojibake..ok that 's what that is...thanks again..i'll update with better example...i'll also have to avoid mojibake in the first place..

Comment: It's possible that `unicodedata` doesn't have records for some of the most recently added characters. You might need to just put a `try`/`except` around it.

Comment: agreed...i'd rather use my own look up. I'm fighting with pandas right now to form the proper dict from a text file I made from that link in the question.

Comment: Pandas is probably overkill, that could easily be done with a regular expression. Sorry I don't have time to help out right now.

Comment: Somehow I missed that big `Python 2.7` in the title, I thought by the fact that you weren't using `u''` strings and had parentheses after `print` that you were using Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was in using Python2.7 for the unicodedata module.
using Conda I created a python 3.3 environment and now unicodedata works
as expected and I've given up on all weird hacks I was working on.

```
# using python 3.3
import unicodedata as uni

In [2]: uni.name('\U0001f648')
Out[2]: 'SEE-NO-EVIL MONKEY'
```

Thanks to Mark Ransom for pointing out that I originally had Mojibake from not
correctly importing my data. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to read the link you provided. It's translated from Python 2 so there might be a glitch or two.

```
import re
import urllib2
rexp = re.compile(r'U\+([0-9A-Za-z]+)[^#]*# [^)]*\) *(.*)')
mapping = {}
for line in urllib2.urlopen('ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt'):
    line = line.decode('utf-8')
    m = rexp.match(line)
    if m:
        mapping[chr(int(m.group(1), 16))] = m.group(2)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that regex is helpful. I was having trouble getting my experiments to deal with the unicode. I'm going to work on this later today and will hopefully add more.