# How to determine whether a Python string contains an emoji?

Tags: python, emoji

I've seen previous responses to this question, but none of them are recent and none of them are working for me in Python 3. I have a list of strings, and I simply want to identify which ones contain emoji. What's the fastest way to do this?

To be more specific, I have a lengthy list of email subject lines from AB tests, and I'm trying to determine which subject lines contained emoji.

Comment: Emoticons or emoji? And in any way, you have to define first what this means to you exactly.

Comment: I'd suggest trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28327594/6464893).

Comment: A majority of the previous solutions should translate well to Python 3.  Please post one that strikes you as "ought to work" and the error message, so we can help with your specific problem.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730560/is-there-a-specific-range-of-unicode-code-points-which-can-be-checked-for-emojis

Answer (score 1):

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290240/python-2-7-detect-emoji-from-text/28327594#28327594) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730560/is-there-a-specific-range-of-unicode-code-points-which-can-be-checked-for-emojis) both count © and other common characters as emoji. Also the former has minor mistakes and the latter still doesn't appear to work.

Here's an implementation that errs on the conservative side using [this newer data](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/emoji/3.0/emoji-data.txt) and [this documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/). It only considers code points that are marked with the unicode property `Emoji_Presentation` (which means it's definitely an emoji), or code points marked only with the property `Emoji` (which means it defaults to text but it *could* be an emoji), that are followed by a special variation selector code point `fe0f` that says to default to an emoji instead. The reason I say this is conservative is because certain systems aren't as picky about the `fe0f` and will treat characters as emoji wherever they can (read more about this [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Presentation_Style)).

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict


def parse_line(line):
    """Return a pair (property, codepoints) where property is a string and
       codepoints is a set of int unicode code points"""
    pat = r'([0-9A-Z]+)(\.\.[0-9A-Z]+)? + ; +(\w+) + #.*'
    match = re.match(pat, line)
    assert match

    codepoints = set()

    start = int(match.group(1), 16)

    if match.group(2):
        trimmed = match.group(2)[2:]
        end = int(trimmed, 16) + 1
    else:
        end = start + 1

    for cp in range(start, end):
        codepoints.add(cp)

    return (match.group(3), codepoints)


def parse_emoji_data():
    """Return a dictionary mapping properties to code points"""
    result = defaultdict(set)
    with open('emoji-data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if '#' != line[0] and len(line.strip()) > 0:
                property, cp = parse_line(line)
                result[property] |= cp
    return result


def test_parse_emoji_data():
    sets = parse_emoji_data()
    sizes = {
        'Emoji': 1123,
        'Emoji_Presentation': 910,
        'Emoji_Modifier': 5,
        'Emoji_Modifier_Base': 83,
    }
    for k, v in sizes.items():
        assert len(sets[k]) == v


def contains_emoji(text):
    """
    Return true if the string contains either a code point with the
    `Emoji_Presentation` property, or a code point with the `Emoji`
    property that is followed by \uFE0F
    """
    sets = parse_emoji_data()
    for i, ch in enumerate(text):
        if ord(ch) in sets['Emoji_Presentation']:
            return True
        elif ord(ch) in sets['Emoji']:
            if len(text) > i+1 and text[i+1] == '\ufe0f':
                return True
    return False

test_parse_emoji_data()
assert not contains_emoji('hello')
assert not contains_emoji('hello :) :D 125% #%&*(@#%&!@(^*(')
assert contains_emoji('here is a smiley \U0001F601 !!!')
```

To run this you need ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/emoji/3.0/emoji-data.txt in the working directory.

Once the regex module supports emoji properties it will be easier to use that instead.